# Jekyll GitHub Issues API use

Tags: json, github, jekyll

I'm a beginner of web programming.

Jekyll(GitHub Pages Tool) can do many thing, easily make static website.

I think if i could make a web community with Github Pages including Issues API, that would be really cool.

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

But i'm not certain that static website can use API well. I wasn't able to find certain jekyll plugins.

Can I use GitHub Issues api on GitHub Pages, view/open/close issues on xxx.github.io?

I would really appreciate if you let me know in detail, but I will be studying json soon, so it's okay to let me know just about whether or not.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no, Jekyll does not help you with this.

So maybe the first thing to clarify is that Jekyll is just a way of making it easier to build your site without having to repeat a bunch of HTML code — you can use templates and some basic programming functionality to have that code generated automatically for you into ready-to-serve HTML files. It only interacts with the content in your site directory. It is not meant to provide server-like functionality or transfer/receive data from a server.

What you're wanting to do — interact with a third-party API and display returned data on your webpage — is an entirely separate concern. You'll do that using client-side Javascript, meaning Javascript files stored in your site files that are loaded into your HTML page through script tags. The main issue with this is that you don't really have a way to hide your API token, which is essentially giving your login details to whoever views your site's source files (which is really easy to do), depending on what permissions you've set for that token.

With something like this where you're accessing protected data in an API, you'll usually want to run a server that can make those calls for you without exposing your token in a publicly served file. You then interact with that server from your client-side Javascript, and you can put protections in place on the server-side to ensure certain actions can't be done by just anyone. You can do something like this for free with [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and following [one](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd) of many Node.js tutorials out there.

Comment: Thank you! There should be an intermediate server to hide the token and keep it secure...